# Seleccionar dispositivos no compatibles con una app en swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Tengo una duda, yo estoy desarrollando una app en siwft 4, sin embargo la app que se desarrolla no tiene como objetivo las IPad, hay una forma de mostrar un alert o algo o de plano no dejar instalar la app si se detecta que es una IPad? Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola eso lo podes poner en la configuracion del target.

Selecciona el Target->General->Deployment Info. Ahi dentro esta la opcion Devices, por defecto viene seteado en Universal, lo que significa que es una app tanto para iPad como iPhone. Cambia esa configuracion seleccionando iPhone y ahora tu app es solo para iphones.

Te dejo un ScreenShoot por las dudas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, es bastante sencillo, pero no lo había visto, muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada @JudáEscalera. Si la respuesta te sirvio marcala como correcta. Abrazo.